What to use piechart in React native 0.74 version
I want to use piechart in React my react native version 0.74 earlier I was using 0.63 and reactnnative piechart package was working fine so now I installed react native gifted charts for the same but this error is coming after that

SDK proces react native but when upgraded. This version only
understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4
was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio
and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not
determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. >
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > A problem occurred configuring project
':react-native-gps-state'. > Could not determine the dependencies of
null. > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration
':react-native-gps-state:classpath'. > Could not find
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3. Searched in the following
locations: -
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
Required by: project :react-native-gps-state * Try: > If the artifact
you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without
metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the
'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration. > Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at
https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s. Either suggest me some other package or please
resolve this issue my gradle version is 8.2

I want to use piechart anyhow

If you only need a pie chart and labels are not required you can simply use react-native-pie-chart
https://github.com/aidin36/react-native-pie-chart
